# Why is my INT variable being passed by reference?? C#

Tags: c#, delegates, closures, pass-by-reference, value-type

Ok so I know the difference (I think) between value types and reference types in C#. However, the code below does not behave the way I would expect knowing what I know about value types and reference types.

```
delegate void SomeHandler();

static Action GetSomeHandler()
 {
   int x = 1;

   SomeHandler a = delegate { Console.WriteLine(x); };

   x = 2;

   return a;
 }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SomeHandler a = GetSomeHandler();

   a();
}
```

I'm confused because a local variable "x" is declared and initialized to 1 inside my GetSomeHandler method. Then, a new delegate "a" of type SomeHandler is declared and assigned to an anonymous method that writes "x" to the console. 
"x" is then assigned to 2. Finally, "a" is invoked and the value of "x" is printed to the console.

I expected the output to be 1 because "x" is an int (a value type) and I would assume that when 2 was assigned to "x" it would not affect what I have used in my delegate because the value would be copied and not pointed to the same location in memory but the actual output is 2!! WHY!?

Comment: Delegates are different. You are actually referring to the same variable `x` both inside the delegate and outside it. This causes a lot of confusion with `for` loops: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: It's a closure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Comment: @EdS. could you elaborate?

Comment: @Blorgbeard why would delegates be different?

Comment: @Jason's answer explains it pretty well. You are not *passing* `x` to the delegate - the delegate is simply referring to the variable `x`, in the same way that `x = 2;` is. Since the delegate code is executed after `x` has been set to 2, that's the value that you see.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Oh is what Jason said correct? I wasn't sure because not that many people upvoted it and I wanted to make sure he knew what he was talking about.

Comment: Yes, as far as my knowledge goes (not as far as what the compiler does internally), he is correct. +2 is pretty good for 29 views on the question. Incorrect answers will usually be at a negative score fairly quickly.

Comment: Not that you have any particular reason to believe that I know what I'm talking about either ;)

Comment: @Blorgbeard thank you for your input! I just saw that you had very high reputation so I figured I could trust you haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, you have discovered the magic of **closures**!

You are correct in thinking that "x" is a value type and that it should not behave in this way; that is if you weren't declaring an anonymous function inside of your method. An anonymous method is a closure and is bound to its parenting method body and the local variables in it (In this case it is the local variable "x" and the parenting method GetSomeHandler).

The important distinction is that it is bound to *variables*, not to *values*. In other words, the value of "x" is not copied in when "a" is declared. Instead, a "reference" to "x" is used so that "a" will always use the most recent value of "x". In fact, this "reference" to "x" will be persisted even if "x" goes out of scope. When you compile your program the compiler then works some of its "compiler magic" and generates something similar to the following snippet of code:

```
delegate void SomeHandler();

// This is the helper class generated by the compiler that allows an anonymous function inside your method access to local variables even after the function or method has returned.
sealed class SomeHandlerClosure
{
   public int x;

   public void CompilerNamedMethod()
   {
     Console.WriteLine(x);
   }
}

static SomeHandler GetSomeHandler()
 {
   SomeHandlerClosure closure = new SomeHandlerClosure();
   closure.x = 1;

   SomeHandler a = new SomeHandler(closure.CompilerNamedMethod);

   closure.x = 2;

   return a;
 }

static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   SomeHandler a = GetSomeHandler();

   a();
 }
```

The "GetSomeHandler" method is really where the magic happens:

1.At the beginning of method, an instance of the "SomeClosure" class is created. (Note that I chose to use the names "SomeHandlerClosure" and "CompilerNamedMethod" for clarity. In reality, the compiler generates names to prevent name collision.)

2.All references to the local variable "x" in the "GetSomeHandler" method have been replaced with references to the "x" field on the "SomeHandlerClosure" instance.

3.The delegate "a" is now assigned to a new delegate instance for "CompilerNamedMethod" on the "SomeHandlerClosure" instance.

Clear as mud??